# customize solution environment

Tags: r, bookdown, quarto

I'm trying to automate the insertion of horizontal rules at the end of solution environments in Quarto; for example:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
---

:::{#exr-oneplusone}
What is 1+1?

::::{.solution}
$$1+1 = 2$$

******

::::



:::
```

I'm trying to insert

```
******
```

at the end of every `.solution` environment, or maybe the exercise environment.

From https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#theorems, it seems like there's a way to customize the `solution` environment using CSS. I'm just not sure what the syntax is for the CSS file. Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 3):

Here a way: The CSS margin properties are used to create space below and the border mirrors a horizontal line,

```
---
title: "Untitled"
---

<style>
.solution{
    margin: 3px 0px; 
    border-bottom: 0.9px solid black;
}
</style>

:::{#exr-oneplusone}
What is 1+1?

::::{.solution}
$$1+1 = 2$$

::::
:::
```

[image]